# octave plot does not work properly

Tags: matlab, octave

CODE DELETED

Hi, the code above is my (slightly modified) rooo.m file.
I'm just trying to plot the function by typing into (octave) terminal

```
x = 1:1:40;
plot(x, rooo(x), '+');
```

But this will only print the graph of y=1.
I believe it's because of the y = 1; in the first line (btw the function itself returns the right value, say when I type rooo(3)).
When I change it to some other number (say b), the graph will show y =b.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not working because if you type `rooo(x)` at the command line, it will return a scalar result of `1`, instead of a vector. The `1 < n` logical condition doesn't work as you intended to when `n` is a vector.

Here is a suggestion to make it work (maybe not the most elegant but it seems to work):

CODE DELETED

Which, when called as in your question, gives the following plot

[image]

The results seem to be different from the ones reported in MATLAB though.

An alternative, if you don't want to modify your function, is to change the way you call it:

```
>> x = 1:1:40;
>> y = ones(size(x));
>> for k=1:length(x)
y(k) = rooo(x(k));
end
>> plot(x,y,'+')
```

This gives the same result as the above suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you never enter the while loop with `x` starting at 1. Since

`1 < n == 1 < x` is false at the very beginning, the function returns.

However when you call rooo(3) or actually rooo(Anything > 1) it does work. With x = 1.1:1:40 the plot looks like this ( I made it with Matlab) :

[image]

Comment: I believe the resulting graph to be incorrect due to the the vector operations in the `while` loop (e.g. `n--`). If you type `rooo(40)`, you'll see that the answer is 3, no 6 and a bit.